# Prove that complement of the interior equals closure of the complement

Tags: general-topology

I tried as follows:

- If *x* is not in the interior of set *E*, then no neighborhood of *x* is contained in *E*. So for every neighborhood of *x* there is a point *y* which is not in *E*. That is, every neighborhood of *x* contains a point *y* which lies in complement of *E*. So *x* is a limit point of complement of *E*.
  -

On the other hand, if *y* is in closure of complement of *E*, then *y* is in *E* complement or set of all limit points of it. In the first case we are done since *Int(E)* is contained in *E*.

- In the second case, *y* is the limit point of complement of *E*. So every neighborhood of *y* contains a point which is not in *E*. Hence no neighborhood of *y* completely lies in *E*. Thus *y* is not an interior point of *E*.

Is this correct??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your proof is kind of hard to read.  It seems like it could use some paragraph breaks or something.

Comment: I think it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let X be discrete, E = X - {a}.  Assume x in interior E.
In your 1st proof, you conclude x is a limit point of the
complement of E, namely {a} which has no limit points.

That example shows your proof is wrong.
You do however, have the right idea.
Use the right definition of closure:
the set of all adherence points.
a is an adherance point of A when for all
open U nhood a, U $\cap$ A is not empty.

Comment: Oh yes. You are right. Whether this proof works?: Let x be not in Int(E). On the contrary assume that x is not in closure of E complement. Then there is a nbhd U of x such that U and complement of E have no points in common. Then U is contained in E so that x will be in Int(E) which is a contradiction

Comment: @USK.  Now you know the folly of limit points which topologically are a minor topic.